# Conditionals do not work in . ./script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am trying to make a history file manipulations scripts.

When I try to, for instance implement an incognito mode by running

```
unset HISTFILE
```

It doesn't work due to command running in new shell. When I try

```
. ./script
```

The command works, but conditionals I use to process arguments passed to script cause syntax error.

<s>Is there any workaround for this?</s>
Solved: the issue was wrong conditionals usage and unadaptation of script for zsh.

```
case $1 in
    (set)
        HISTFILE=$2
        HISTFILESIZE=$3
        ;;
    (incognito)
        unset HISTFILE
        ;;
    (removesizelimit)
        HISTSIZE=-1
        HISTFILESIZE=-1
        ;;
    (clear)
        rm -f $HISTFILE
        unset HISTFILE && exit
        ;;
    (backup)
        tar -cf HISTFILE.tar $HISTFILE
        ;;
    ("")
        echo "Usage:"
        echo " . ./history <option>"
        echo " . ./history set <HISTSIZE> <HISTFILESIZE>"
        echo
        echo "Manipulate history file"
        echo
        echo "Options:"
        echo -e " incognito\t\t\tdo not record history of commands in this session"
        echo -e " removesizelimit\t\tremove limitation of size of history file"
        echo -e " clear\t\t\t\tclear history of run commands"
        echo -e " backup\t\t\t\tclear create a backup of history file in archive"
        ;;
    (*)
        echo "ERROR: Option unrecognized"
        echo
        echo "run . ./history for help"
esac
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant section(s) from your script, and the error messages you receive. Otherwise we have zero chance of helping identify the errors.

Comment: What arguments?

Comment: What errors do you get when you run the script? _How_ do you run the script? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Tangential to the question, but I would recommend against using `#!/bin/bash` as that is a marker that the script is executable stand-alone (which it is not).

Comment: What is your login shell? Is it actually `bash`, or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n.b. most of this answer made much more sense before the question's edit :)

The mistake is a simple one:

```bash
if [ "$1" == "proto" ]; then
    TESTVAR=
if [ "$1" == "set" ]; then
    HISTFILE=$2
    HISTFILESIZE=$3
elif [ "$1" == "incognito" ]; then
# ....
```

The second `if` here should be `elif`. `bash` is complaining because it can't find a matching `fi`.

There are also two other things I'd like to mention about the script:

1. This will run in a subshell and execute the output of the `unset` command, which is not what you want:

   ```
   $(unset HISTFILE)
   ```

   You should remove the `$(...)` operator from it.
2. The `#!/bin/bash` implies that the script is executable stand-alone as an argument to the `/bin/bash` binary. That doesn't make sense for a script like this, so I would advise against it (and I would advise against setting the executable permission on it).

---

One last thing. Argument parsing via nested if/else is a bit of a clunky way to do things. You can use a `case` statement:

```bash
case $1 in
    (proto) TESTVAR= ;;
    (set)
        HISTFILE=$2
        HISTFILESIZE=$3
        ;;
    #...etc...
    ("")
        # ... put your usage here...
        ;;
    (*)
        echo >&2 "ERROR: Option unrecognized"
        echo >&2
        echo >&2 "run . ./history.bash for help"
        ;;
esac
```

---

Making the script work under zsh:

1. Replace usage of `==` with `=`. The `==` operator is a non-standard alias to the `=` operator, and this is one of the cases in which it breaks.
2. Rename `HISTFILESIZE` to `SAVEHIST`

Comment: Tacked on some zsh instructions. That said I don't think `SAVEHIST`/`HISTSIZE` being set to `-1` works on `zsh`. I don't know the equivalent.

Comment: Works, thanks for your detailed answer and help ^^ :)